# Inversion with phrase "handy for"

Tags: grammar, semantics, rhetorical-devices

The following example sentence from [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/handy) seems to me perfectly natural and in line with the given definition of *handy*:

> 3. A thing or place that is handy is nearby and therefore easy to get or reach.
>
> This lively town is handy for Londoners.

However, the phrase *[the house is] handy for the shops* (a lot of examples of which can be found by [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22handy%20for%20the%20shops%22)) seems semantically inverted with regard to the definition above: It is the shops that are handy and near the house which its residents can readily access the shop, not vice vera.

I know that nearness is usually a reciprocal relation*; However, as I mentioned earlier, the view point is different.

Am I correct in that respect? Is any rhetorical device at work here?

<sup>* Except when, for example, shops are at top of a hill above the house so that the house is, literally speaking, handy for the shops.</sup>

Comment: ***Handy*** can be used to mean ***convenient*** - often *conveniently **located***, but it can just mean *conveniently **available***, as in *Before we had accurate digital timepieces, the [Speaking Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaking_clock) was handy for checking the exact time.* Personally, I have no problem with *My house is handy for the shops*.

Comment: Following the pattern of _This lively town is handy **for Londoners**_ and because _the shops are conveniently located **for the household**_ not vice versa (i.e. _the house is conveniently located **for the shopworkers**_), I think we should say **the shops are handy**.

Comment: We ***could*** say *The shops are handy* - for something / someone contextually relevant (such as *my house, me*), but I don't see where ***should*** comes into it. I think you're assuming a "teleology" or something that simply doesn't apply here (to do with whether or not things can be "handy" relative to something that cannot have "purpose").

Comment: I think it partly depends on what you are emphasizing--the location of the house, or the location of the shops.

Comment: @FumbleFingers & RobJarvis I'm not speaking about whether something could be handy for a shop or for a shopworker. I'm wondering whether it's semantically correct to mention in a **flat** rental ad that _The flat is handy for the shops_?

Comment: First you say you're NOT *speaking about whether something could be **handy for a shop***, then you ask whether it makes sense to say *The flat is **handy for the shops***. If you're just worried about the switch from singular to plural there, note that it's also fine to say *My house is handy for the village pub* (which is conveniently located right next door to my house! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I meant that I wasn't comparing shops (a thing that has not "purpose") with shopworker (a person who has "purpose"). Neither I'm comparing shop (singular) with shops (plural). I'm wondering whether it's semantically correct to mention in a **flat** rental ad that _The flat is handy for the shops_ instead of _The shops -or the shop for that matter- are handy for the flat_.

Comment: Just about anything (sentient or not) can be "handy" if it's *nearby* and/or *available* and/or *useful* for something. ***Flats*** certainly aren't a special case. I could say ***My daughter's boyfriend** is **handy** for replacing a tap washer*, for example, even if he lives some distance away.

Comment: A house that is handy for the shops means that shopworkers can live there close to work, not that the shops are handy for shopping if you live at that house. *Close to shopping* would refer to the handy location of the house.

Comment: To my Australian ear it comes off as a British phrasing. I understand it but I wouldn't say it.